# can't get the error on next.js server side data fetching

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

i try to get the error on my next.js server side data fetching
but i have 2 problems

```
export async function getStaticProps() {

  try {

    const fetchUrl =

      "some api url";

    const resp = await axios.get(fetchUrl);

    return { props: { articles: resp.data.articles } };

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return { props: { articles: [], error: err } };

  }

}
```

it says err object is not serializable and i can't see console.log result
i try to convert err to string and get **object undefined**

it comes to catch block i check it with assign it "custom error message" but i don't have access to catch's exception message

> the official doc in next.js only uses custom message

Answer (score 0):

The error `Object is not serializable` means that your object cannot be transformed into a JSON serialized version the way it is (probably the `err` object is too complex).

From your code, it seems that it is most likely an error thrown by axios, so what you could try to send is `err.message` to have the error message. If you want more information, you can check the [axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors). Also keep in mind that `undefined` is not a value that can be serialized, and you should be using `null` instead when needed.